# How to uninstall Intel Linux Graphics Installer and revert to default drivers

Tags: software-installation, intel-graphics

Recently Intel released their opensource driver tool (https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intel-linux-graphics-installer) which auto-selects the right drivers for your intel chipset (in my case, I was using the i915 driver).  Because I started using Steam on Linux to play some older games I thought I would use the Intel 'official' drivers to ensure I get the best performance. Unfortunately, since installing the drivers, the computer fan is very loud and the battery doesn't last that long (it's cut battery life in half). On top of that, there's no noticeable difference when playing games on Steam.

My question is, how do I revert back to the original drivers?

If I run the Intel graphic driver installer I get the following output in the terminal (not in the GUI) so I assume I will somehow need to run apt-get with some type of downgrade flag (I'm not sure how to do that) against these packages.

```
install: [i915-3.4-3.2-dkms libdrm-nouveau2]
upgrade: [libcairo2 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-script-interpreter2 libdrm2 libdrm-intel1 libkms1 libva1 libva-x11-1 libva-glx1 libva-tpi1 libva-egl1 vainfo libxatracker1 libgbm1 libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers libopenvg1-mesa libgles1-mesa libgles2-mesa libglapi-mesa libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental libosmesa6 libglu1-mesa i965-va-driver libva-intel-vaapi-driver xserver-xorg-video-intel libwayland0]
```

When I look at the install logs though, it seems there's much more than that.

Any assistance on this would be most appreciated.

Comment: Sorry... I forgot to mention I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (with latest updates).

Comment: The BEST solution (TESTED):

http://askubuntu.com/questions/531540/how-to-safely-remove-proprietary-intel-driver

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

A solution from http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/04/how-to-add-intel-linux-graphics-driver-repository-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I'm afraid that would only uninstall the installer, but not the drivers and dependencies originally installed by it

Comment: The package is no longer named so. I get `E: Unable to locate package intel-linux-graphics-installer`

Comment: Now the package is named `intel-graphics-update-tool` so the full command is `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge intel-graphics-update-tool` and it works for me.

Comment: yep, it's confirmed `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge intel-graphics-update-tool` works

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

```
#source http://theclonker.de/?p=89
sudo sh -c 'echo "\nPackage: *\nPin: release a=trusty*\nPin-Priority: 1001\n\nPackage: *\nPin: origin download.01.org\nPin-Priority: -100\n" > /etc/apt/preferences.d/intel-removal'
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/intel-removal
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list*
sudo apt-get update
echo "\n\n\n\n\n\n Remember to remove the i915-3.6-3.5-dkms and intel-linux-graphics-installer packages with \n\n sudo apt-get purge i915-3.6-3.5-dkms intel-linux-graphics-installer "
```

You should change the `i915-3.6-3.5-dkms` package name to your version.

Source: https://gist.github.com/phdelodder/b28e8df770a6bc020aab

The original source http://theclonker.de/?p=89 was removed.

Comment: Note the way to find your current i915-dkms version so that you can `apt-get purge` it is to run: `dpkg --get-selections | grep i915`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution to your problem http://theclonker.de/?p=89

Comment: thanks a million! I'll try this later tonight. Hopefully I'll not destroy my system in the process :)

Comment: Hopefully your system will be ok :) I have tried those steps and it solves mine. Btw, I am using ubuntu 12.10

Comment: I did a thorough review, it seems that this method will only replace the actual driver without uninstalling the MANY dependencies which were installed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Guys.. this question can be closed.  I got fed-up with this issue and decided to do something a little drastic - I simply upgraded to 12.10.  It's resolved my issue for now.

Answer (score 3):

In the end I found this to be too frustrating to wait for the right answer. In order to fix the situation, I upgraded to version 12.10. It completely wiped all traces of the Intel drivers and I now have a quiet and cooler laptop.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use the ppa-purge tool:

```
sudo ppa-purge -s download.01.org ppa:gfx/ubuntu
```

This will disable the intel repository and downgrade all packages that were installed from this repository.

Answer (score 0):

In later versions the name has changed; to remove you need to run the following:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge intel-graphics-update-tool
```