# Experiencing major issues on graphic displays

Tags: 12.04, xorg, intel-graphics, flash

Since installing Ubuntu 12.04, I am experiencing low performance on graphic programs, including video playbacks, etc.

As I have checked the intel driver of mine is already at its latest version. It's really occuring meanwhile playback of videos or web-flash videos (youtube, etc) OS is being logged out automatically and just display an error reporting of Xorg windows for me. I can not actually playback hd videos with the normal frame rate as well.
here are some initiation of my graphic card details :

```
*-display:0             
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:45 memory:f6c00000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:efe8(size=8)
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
   description: Display controller
   product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2.1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f6b00000-f6bfffff
```

and the intel model:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

Edited: A little more information :

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Username Info:

```
Linux amir-laptop 3.2.0-53-generic-pae #81-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 21:23:47 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Xorg info :

```
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel               2:2.17.0-1ubuntu4.4                       X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
```

Comment: How did you check that driver is the latest?

Comment: @Mitch, I used this (https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) ppa to bring the latest intel-xorg driver and then I upgrade && update it

Comment: If you're running 12.04 32bit, you may want to try the [Intel Graphics Installer](http://ubuntuone.com/2X1R6qw7TjCsTyC6mPF7uV).

Comment: tnx, let me try it and will be back on you ;)

Comment: I had the same problem and fixed it. First I want from you to paste the result of these commands: 1. `sudo lsb_release -a` 2. `sudo uname -a` and 3. `sudo dpkg -l | grep video-intel`

Comment: Tnx SauravKumar for the suggestion, but I ran into a horrible problem now!! @Mitch, when I tried to install your debian package, the installer refused because of a dependency issue with libglib2-0-0 which my version was older than 2.35, I tried to remove the libglb and update it but as some points I found out every  single components of Ubuntu 12.04 has been being removing line by line! the system haulted and after restart I Don't even have the Ubuntu to start up with. there;s only the Memory test remained, How am I gonna be able to recover my Ubuntu ?? :(

Comment: I'm really sorry that that happened to you :(  I just wish that you haven't tried to remove libglb and update it.  Take a look at [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94542/how-can-i-repair-my-installation), see if it helps you recover.  Please let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: Also you may want to take a look at [How to uninstall Intel Linux Graphics Installer and revert to default drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280593/how-to-uninstall-intel-linux-graphics-installer-and-revert-to-default-drivers).

Comment: Alright @Mitch. Tnx buddy. I'll be back

Comment: @Amir To fix the problem of many inadvertently removed packages, see [Andrea Corbellini's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/249373/22949) to [How to fix Ubuntu after accidentally uninstalling many packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/249367/how-to-fix-ubuntu-after-accidentally-uninstalling-many-packages). (Of course this question is **not** a duplicate of that; that's just the solution to accidentally removing lots of packages.)

Comment: @Mitch, i managed to retrieve the OS ;)

Comment: @SauravKumar, I added the requested info in the edited part of the question ;)

Comment: @Amir: Give me some time! The process is so long! I'm still thinking from where to start.. Anyway I'll post it, but I expect from your to follow it precisely!!

Comment: @SauravKumar, alright ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these steps precisely!

1. Run following command in terminal and `tick` all check boxes under <kbd>Ubuntu Software</kbd> and <kbd>Updates</kbd> tabs. If already ticked then leave it.

   ```
   sudo software-properties-gtk
   ```

   then update your repository:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install `Linux Kernel 3.8.0` by selecting following packages in `Synaptic`:

   ```
   linux-generic-lts-raring
   linux-headers-3.8.0-30
   linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic
   linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
   linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic
   linux-image-generic-lts-raring
   ```

   you can also install `Kernel 3.8.x` by executing following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring linux-headers-3.8.0-30 linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-raring linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic linux-image-generic-lts-raring
   ```

   Once installed execute following command to update-grub and reboot your system(be sure to select `Kernel 3.8.0.30` from your grub menu):

   ```
   sudo update-grub && sudo reboot
   ```

   Before trying to *3rd* step I just want you to try *4th* step. If it fixes your problem then no need to install latest `Xserver-Xorg` packages so you can skip *3rd* step.
3. Install all `-lts-raring` packages for `Xserver-Xorg` using following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring libxatracker1-lts-raring xserver-xorg-core-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-s3-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-sis-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-raring libxrandr-ltsq2 x11-xserver-utils-lts-raring xserver-common-lts-raring
   ```

   Why this list is so long because I ensure that you install all `lts-raring` packages for `xserver-xorg`. I recommend you to copy and paste it in terminal. It will remove already installed Xserver-Xorg packages which was meant for previous kernel. so press `y` when it prompts to remove such packages.. Run this command to ensure you installed all:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-lts-raring
   ```
4. Now execute following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')
   ```

   If last step shows some error, then execute these commands `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get --purge remove`, `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean`.

   Then again try to run the command that gives you error. If still it gives you the same error then replace that command with this one: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep 'lts-raring' | tr '\n' ' ')`.

   Then continue to next:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

   Then restart your system again:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
5. After reboot your system should work great.

**A short description of all steps mentioned above:**

*1st* Step ensures that you'll able to download `lts-raring` packages.

In *2nd* step you are installing a good stable kernel for your system, you are using so old kernel: `3.2.x`.

*3rd* Step will install `Xserver-Xorg` packages including `graphics card driver` which is best supported by `Kernel 3.8.0`

*4th* Step is used to re-configure the packages installed in your system to latest kernel just you installed.

It is not that much tough, I did it without any problem. And my system works great now! If you get any problem or error at any particular step, just reply mentioning that command with the error. I'll be waiting for your reply..

Comment: I have reached till step 4, but I am receiving : "/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: xserver-xorg is broken or not fully installed" by executing the second dpkg-reconfigure command, what do you suggest ?

Comment: Did you reach step 4 by completing step 3? It is important to know! and can you copy and paste the command here which gives you that message..?

Comment: Yes, I did them one by one sequentially. amir@amir-laptop:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: xserver-xorg is broken or not fully installed

Comment: Great! You are near to fix your problem!! :) run these commands in series: `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get --purge remove`, `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean`. Then again try to run the command that gives you error. If still it gives you the same error then replace that command with this command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep 'lts-raring' | tr '\n' ' ')` Then restart your system.. Hope after restarting your system.. Your problem would be solved.. and don't forget to execute command after that..

Comment: no need for the last one anymore? : "sudo update-initramfs -u"

Comment: Yes, I forget to tell you.. You have to execute that.. ;) Do it..

Comment: I am back after the reboot, now I've got :                       rc  xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.17.0-1ubuntu4.4                     X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
                                                                ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring         2:2.21.6-0ubuntu4.1~precise1            X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver

Comment: So your issue solved or not? Are you getting any error?

Comment: generally, how am I gonna be able to test the new version in ubutnu  ? to see if this works flawless or not ?

Comment: By running videos and other graphics programs.. as you mentioned above.. You should get less or no lagging and sluggishness this time..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10568/discussion-between-saurav-kumar-and-amir)

Comment: Tnx buddy. it seems fine. if you edit the last step in your answer I will accept it ;) The performance seems fine, however, yet I am having one of the ex-issue s with me and that is freezing the system and a white screen after a couple of switches between normal screen and full screen while playing video on browsers.

Comment: and for an unknown reason I can not answer you in chat. but please let me know about the xorg.conf ;)

Comment: @Amir: If everything is working fine, then I recommend you not to create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. I've edited my answer verify it, and edit if I missed something..

Comment: Everything is fine except the issue that mentioned above. white screen freezing...

Comment: @Amir: I'm not sure what that screen is.. But you can follow some more steps to solve that.. So for that it is very necessary to come with chat.. I've to give suggestions that you have to follow and reply soon, and again it will go so long.. :) It would be better if this conversation is started with chat..

Comment: do u know any info about my question asked here : `http://askubuntu.com/questions/385478/increasing-the-onboard-graphic-memory-card-for-intel-gm45-series` couldn't find you in chat or via email. thanks ;)

Comment: sry for bothering again, recently I have installed ubuntu_12.04_64bits, with `Linux amir-laptop 3.8.0-39-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 1 20:04:50 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` again I am having the poor flash playbacks on web, should I use the same header package and use a newer version of that compatible with my headers ?

Comment: @Amir: You can give it a try. As I've mentioned already that sometime the linux kernel and the driver packages are not compatible and cause such issue. You can give a try to upgrade your system to [**Next Hardware Enablement Stack**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/336527/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-2-12-04-3-to-12-04-4-the-next-hardware-enablement). Go for my latest answer. Also check whether you're using Ubuntu **12.04.4** by executing this command: `lsb_release -d`.