# Increasing the onboard graphic memory card for intel-Gm45 series

Tags: xorg, mesa

Recently I have upgraded my RAM modules to 2*4GB 800 Mhz dual-channels. I have 10GB swap space as well in my Ubuntu 12.04. Kinda weird that I don't have the options for manipulating the onboard graphic card on the BIOS (Inspiron-1545, BIOS Ver. A14). Still written 32 MB in BIOS after changing my RAM modules.

Now I have 256M as aperture, Any idea how to increase that manually to have better performance on HD videos? and someone please explain the differences between this 32MB of BIOS and 256MB of aperture.

Here are some info of my system and the graphic card benchmark:

```
=======================================================
glmark2 2011.09
=======================================================
OpenGL Information
GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center
GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset 
GL_VERSION:    2.1 Mesa 9.1.7
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false:  FPS: 300
[build] use-vbo=true:  FPS: 325
[texture] texture-filter=nearest:  FPS: 374
[texture] texture-filter=linear:  FPS: 375
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap:  FPS: 410
[shading] shading=gouraud:  FPS: 250
[shading] shading=blinn-phong-inf:  FPS: 260
[shading] shading=phong:  FPS: 222
[bump] bump-render=high-poly:  FPS: 156
[bump] bump-render=normals:  FPS: 353
[effect2d] kernel=0,1,0;1,-4,1;0,1,0;:  FPS: 145
[effect2d] kernel=1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;:  FPS: 72
[pulsar] light=false:quads=5:texture=false:  FPS: 300
[desktop] blur-radius=5:effect=blur:passes=1:separable=true:windows=4:  FPS: 74
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=0:  FPS: 327
[conditionals] fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=0:  FPS: 268
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=5:  FPS: 327
[function] fragment-complexity=low:fragment-steps=5:  FPS: 324
[function] fragment-complexity=medium:fragment-steps=5:  FPS: 242
[loop] fragment-loop=false:fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=5:  FPS: 315
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=false:vertex-steps=5:  FPS: 315
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=true:vertex-steps=5:  FPS: 226
=======================================================
glmark2 Score: 270 
=======================================================
```

Graphic card info:

```
[0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[0.718565] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: AGP aperture is 256M @ 0xe0000000
```

Comment: Sorry Amir, I've no idea about it..

Comment: @Saurav: no problem buddy ;) tnx anyways

Comment: I think if you can't change it in BIOS then there is no way to change it. i915 kernel module and intel xorg DDX both do not allow you to specify aperture size. I think the BIOS has to initialize it on system POST.

Comment: tnx for the reply. i myself think yes unfortunately :(