# None of the peripherals(eth, USB ) working after upgrading to kernel version 3.8.5 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, usb, kernel, ethernet

I have been using Ubuntu from a long time but I had never been in the depth of Ubuntu. At present I am using Ubuntu `12.04 LTS`. It was getting hanged randomly and fast when I was using Firefox. I search a bit and found that possible solution is to upgrade kernel.

Earlier my kernel was(I am not sure though) `3.5.x` something and then I upgrade it to `3.8.8` using [this link](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/03/linux-kernel-3-8-5-releasedhow-to-install-upgrade-in-ubuntu/) and then after reboot when I open Ubuntu, graphics which was ugly earlier was perfectly fine but no other peripheral work other then VGA port.

I don't know what I had done wrong, and I am unable to post any other related info as even internet is not working in Ubuntu. Had I done anything wrong like upgrading Linux kernel of Ubuntu `12.04` to a kernel version which is not supported?

please help me.

Comment: Have you configured all the installed packages after installing the kernel?

Comment: @SauravKumar: How to do so?i don't know, i had upgraded kernel for the very first time

Comment: Ok let me post it. Hope it would work for you too..

Answer (score 0):

Go through following steps to re-configure all the packages installed in you system.

1. Open the terminal and execute these commands one after other.

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   <sub>`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` would take some time approx. 5-10 minutes, bases on the packages installed in your system. So wait for it to finish. It won't give any error or message if executes successfully.</sub>
2. Then restart your system once. You can use following command to restart:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

Reply if all goes well or you get any trouble at any command or any error message.

**Edit**

Since it is confirmed that the kernel you installed doesn't support, I suggest you to install the kernel from the default **Ubuntu Repository**. Since you installed the kernel **3.8.x** not from the repository but from other places, it would be the reason that you get that much trouble. You can install the same kernel version i,e **3.8.x** from the repository in Ubuntu **12.04**.

Since many have got similar issues, including me, I've already solved it before.
I'm providing the link that can help you:

[Experiences major issues on graphics displays](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342276/experiencing-major-issues-on-graphic-displays/344625#344625)

Except **3rd step** just go through it precisely. Reply if you get any trouble.

Comment: I didn't get any error but a message after `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` that `Package `libmysqlclients18` is not installed and no info is available Use dpkg --info(= dpkg-deb --info) to list their contents and dpkg --contents(= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents. usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure : libmysqlclinet18 is not installed`

Comment: I didnt get my system working still

Comment: There would be two reasons that you're getting these issues: 1. It would be possible that the kernel you installed doesn't support and 2. You might have **residual configuration** or **broken packages** or **both**. You can check (list) **residual configuration** and **broken packages** by executing this command: `sudo dpkg -l | grep -e "^rc" -e "^iU"`. If it gives any output, means you've either **rc** or **broken packages** where **rc** is **residual packages** and **iU** means **broken packages**.. Reply..

Comment: i think the kernel support Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and i didn't get any output after `dpkg -l | grep -e "^rc" -e "^iU"`.Well i am posting one more question regarding why i opted for a kernel upgrade.

Comment: @shailendra: Now it is confirmed that the kernel you installed doesn't support. I just wanted from you to confirm this. You can solve your issue, if you install the kernel from the default **Ubunut Repository** instead downloading the binary file and installing it. I'm editing my answer..