# Need to update to latest supported kernel version in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, upgrade, kernel

Right now i am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with kernel as `3.8.0-35-generic` , while i use this kernel i face a lot of problems
i) Graphics of my LCD screen connected to my laptop via VGA cable appears to be too bad.
ii) Mozilla Firefox is too slow and system get totally hanged.I had to restart it again by power button.[image]. Here is the screen-shot.Every Icon is so big in mirror display.When i search a lot on Firefox getting hanged, i found that it;s a bug being and possible solution is to upgrade the kernel.

Well while i upgrade kernel, Display was too good and really i loved that.
[image]
But suddenly i found that none of the peripheral was working else than VGA port.I upgraded my Ubuntu to `3.8.5-030805-generic`.USB, RJ45(for ethernet), Wifi , none was working.I also posted a question on Ubuntu.Here is [the link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396387/none-of-the-peripheralseth-usb-working-after-upgrading-to-kernel-version-3-8/396396?noredirect=1#comment508270_396396). But i got no useful reply that would have solve my problem. And that's why i have to turn back to my older version.I don't want to re-install Ubuntu 13.04 with latest kernel as there are lot of useful packages that i had installed in my system.So if there any option so that i can make my present system with Ubuntu 12.04 fast with same kernel `3.8.0-35-generic` or if i can upgrade to 13.04 or 13.10( i know i am just asking question assuming it would be easy, but it is not).

Need help, i have been using Ubuntu from last 2 years and i love working on it but i had never been to kernel upgrade earlier.

Edit: I had found a long way to upgrade to 12.10 and then to 13.04 from Ubuntu upgrade notes.I must have searched this earlier, but my rest of questions are still open

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel is not completely up to date - the newest version should be available if you upgrade to 13.10 from 13.04 which is possible with do-release-upgrade or software updater. Then your kernel can automatically be updated.