# Firefox flickering issue

Tags: firefox, video, flicker, hardware-acceleration

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04

The image below shows the problem with the new animated homepage. I got the same kind of problems  with some some videos that **don't** come from youtube.

[image]

It seems like there is some problem regarding hardware acceleration or something like that.

I installed the latest Intel drivers.

But 3D Games from [Steam](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/steam-launcher/) work very good for example.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the latest intel drivers. Did you install them through the "Intel Graphics Installer for Linux"?

Comment: @SimonCharette Sure; but now I just added a new Nvidia card and then I also (hardly) uninstalled the Intel drivers. This is not a solution :)

Comment: How to remove Intel driver: http://askubuntu.com/questions/531540/how-to-safely-remove-proprietary-intel-driver

Comment: As pointed above the solution is to remove Intel drivers http://askubuntu.com/questions/531540/how-to-safely-remove-proprietary-intel-driver.

Comment: Does anybody know a solution without removing intel drivers? I have only 1 GPU and it is integrated Intel HD4000.