# How to fix black screen after Intel Graphics Installer on 14.10?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

I upgraded 14.04 to 14.10 without issues. Then I installed fresh video drivers with Intel Graphics Installer without any errors. But after reboot I have black screen with blinking cursor.

After that, I tried to:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

but it didn't help.
What should I do to revert the driver installation or somehow fix the driver?

**Update:** I also made everything like said in [How to safely remove proprietary Intel driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531540/how-to-safely-remove-proprietary-intel-driver) and everything has done well, but blank screen still there.

Comment: You should downgrade all of the packages that were upgraded and then remove Intel's repository. You could also just pin down Intel's repository and let APT do the work for you. I'm unable to give you step-by-step instructions on how to do that, but hopefully someone else will be able to.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded system to 15.04 and after that everything works fine.